# Backbone Collection has no method add (in Coffeescript)

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm playing with CoffeeScript and am running into a really frustrating error. I have a collection (which I'm populating from an ajax call -- not `fetch()` -- since I need to tweak the JSON that gets returned)

Here's the **collection**

```
$ ->
  class AppName.Members extends Backbone.Collection
    model: AppName.Member
```

And the **model**

```
$ ->
  class AppName.Member extends Backbone.Model
```

Pretty simple, right? Eventually I'll build these out to take non-filler data, but for now this is how it is. And now for my **view**

```
$ ->
  class AppName.TitleView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST['templates/title']
    initialize: ->
      @bind(@collection, 'add', @addOne);
      @bind(@collection, 'reset', @addAll);
      @bind(@collection, 'all', @render);
      $.ajax
        dataType: 'json'
        url: '/housemembers'
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          for member in data.results[0].members
            model =   
                state : member.state
                first_name : member.first_name
                middle_name : member.middle_name
                last_name : member.last_name
                next_election : member.next_election
                party : member.party
            AppName.Members.add model

      @
```

What's killing me is that `AppName.Members.add model` fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function Members() {
        Members.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      } has no method 'add'
```

But when I expect the element in Chrome, there is clearly an `add` method on the `Members()` constructor!!!

In fact, dropping in a watch for `AppName.Members.__super__.add` returns a function callback!

So what's going on here? Why isn't `AppName.Members` a full-fledged Backbone collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) is an instance method on collections but you're trying to use it as a class method. You need to create an instance of your collection first:

```
AppName.members = new AppName.Members
```

and then add models to the instance:

```
AppName.members.add model
```

Or if you're trying to add models to `@collection`, then do something like this:

```
$.ajax
  #...
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) =>
    #...
    @collection.add model
```

Comment: This works (somewhat), but I get an undefined is not defined error deeper down in backbone. I will update once I switch out with the non-minified version and figure out how to clear my rake assets path :P

Comment: @CamelBlues: That sounds like something unrelated.

Comment: You are correct, it was quite unrelated. This definitely is the correct answer to my problem, and as an addendum, I also need to make sure my models.coffee was being loaded before the collections.coffee, as the collections didn't know what to make of it's model